# How to login to a user namespace created by unshare?

Tags: linux, namespace, unshare

How to login to a `user namespace` created by `unshare -U` from another terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no such thing as "logging in to a user namespace"; a user namespace is not a virtual machine running a login interface, or something similar!

You can, however, execute a process, for example a shell, in that existing user namespace:

```
nsenter --target $(pidof process_running_in_the_unshare) /usr/bin/zsh
```